# Is it possible to reference an observable's emission when it is used as a buffer boundary?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have two observables. One is a constant stream of events, the other bundles it up with a buffer.

```js
var buttonClick = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
var mouseMove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')


var action = mouseMove
  .buffer(buttonClick)
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .map(p => {

    // I need the last buttonClick emission here

  })

var subscription = action.subscribe(x => { console.log(x) })
```

How can I access the current `buttonClick` inside of the map iteration? I need this in order to obtain the target property attached to the DOM event of the Observable.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try combineLatest on the unbuffered moves:

```
let move$ = mouseMove
  .buffer(buttonClick)
  .flatMap(x => x);

var action = Observable.combineLatest(move$, buttonClick, (move, click) => {move, click})
.map(res => { //do smt with res.move and res.click })
```

If you set up minimal example in a codepen or pastebin, we could refine this further.

As to an alternative, I think you're better off working with the buffered moves instead of flatmapping them. You'd avoid combining each move with the (same) click and you could always just iterate through the moves, don't need a flatmap for that:

```
let moves$ = mouseMove.buffer(buttonClick);
let movesClick$ = Observable.zip(moves$, buttonClick, (moves, click) => {moves, click});
movesClick$.subscribe(res => { //iterate res.moves and use res.click })
```